# Globalização de Mensagens para o Active Directory

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em ASP.NET e usa o Active Directory para autenticação. As mensagens de erro do Active Directory, quando publicado no meu computador, aparecem em Português, mas quando publicado no servidor, eles aparecem em Inglês e devem aparecer em Português. Já coloquei a tag globalization no Web.config e não resolveu. Alguém sabe como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Qual a versão do Windows do servidor? Você tem acesso às configurações dele?

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2. Tenho acesso sim, mas não posso alterar.

Comment: Aí ferrou. Precisa alterar as configurações regionais e de idioma.

Comment: Entendi, mas não gostei, a MS que sempre colabora. Valeu